# How do I create and then modify a Terraform Resource in the same deployment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

### Quick Background

Over the last few years, Azure has rolled out a number of improved offerings in their V3 App Service plans, however these new SKUs are not available on every Deployment Unit within a region. MS [therefore recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#scale-up-from-an-unsupported-resource-group-and-region-combination) that if you plan on using these new tiers, you should:

> When creating the App Service plan, select a Premium V3 tier. This step ensures that the App Service plan is deployed into a deployment unit that supports Premium V3. Then, redeploy your application code into the newly created app. Even if you scale the App Service plan down to a lower tier to save costs, you can always scale back up to Premium V3 because the deployment unit supports it.

### My Problem

I'm building out an Azure environment with Terraform, and I am trying ensure that I can scale to the V3 tiers in future, I therefore want to:

1. Have a variable that accepts a target App Service Plan Tier.
2. Create an App Service Plan using the latest `P0v3` tier to ensure that all current V3 tiers are available.
3. Scale the same App Service Plan created in step 2 to the target App Service Plan Tier.

Coming from BICEP, I've tried just redefining the resource with a dependency on the initial version, but that doesn't work as expected:

variables.tf:

```
variable "asp_tier" {
  description = "App Service Plan Tier"
  default     = "S1"
}

variable "region" {
  description = "Target region for the deployments"
  default     = "westus2"
}
```

app-service-plans.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_example" {
  name     = "Example-Resources"
  location = var.region
}

# Create an App Service Plan on one of the new Premium V3 SKUs.
# This ensures that the App Service deployment has access to all
# tiers, giving us the greatest flexibility later. 
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "fix_asp" {
  name                = "asp-example-01"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_example.location
  sku_name            = "P0v3"
  worker_count        = 1
  os_type             = "Windows"
}

# Error occurs when applying this resource:
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "target_asp" {
  depends_on          = [azurerm_service_plan.fix_asp]
  name                = "asp-example-01"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_example.location
  sku_name            = var.asp_tier
  worker_count        = 1
  os_type             = "Windows"
}
```

The Apply fails with the message:

> **Error:** A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/rg-example/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/asp-example-01" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_service_plan" for more information.

And it is pointing to the instance referenced in "target_asp":

```
│   with azurerm_service_plan.target_asp,
│   on app-service-plans.tf line xx, in resource "azurerm_service_plan" "target_asp":
│   xx: resource "azurerm_service_plan" "target_asp" {
```

How do I create a resource and then modify it later within the same deployment?

Comment: I have a similar issue later in the process where I need to reference the App Service as a backend on Front Door, and then reference the FrontDoorID in the App Service networking?

Comment: If you want to use an existing resource group you first need to import it into the terraform state.

Comment: @MarkoE - thanks, at the point this is running, it's being applied to an empty subscription. The creation of the Resource Group work fine. The issue is when I try and update the App Service Plan that I've just created with more details.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. I don't think that is possible the way you are trying. If you were to wait for the first one to complete successfully and change it afterwards, would that work?

Comment: @MarkoE so long as I can do it in the same deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform's execution model only supports one action per resource instance in a given plan. In situations where multiple underlying API actions are required, Terraform expects the provider to encapsulate that itself so that a single plan and apply can move from nothing existing to everything having been created and made to match the desired state described by the configuration.

If it's necessary to first create the object with a fixed `sku_name` and then make a second API call to update it with another `sku_name` then that functionality would need to be somehow offered by the provider itself, and both calls encapsulated into the "create" action for `azurerm_service_plan`. Without explicit provider support, it won't be possible to describe this series of actions to Terraform in configuration alone.

I would suggest sharing this use-case with the provider development team in the provider's GitHub repository, and then they can consider whether and how to support this situation as part of the provider. If this pair of operations is the officially-documented way to reach this desired state then it's the provider's responsibility to offer a way to implement that advice within Terraform's execution model.

Comment: Cheers - I feared that was the case.